# Relativity theory and time

Tags: relativity

In relativity theory it is accepted that speed of light is invariant and even time is flexible. Can the mathematics of relativity be interpreted in such a way that time is invariant and everything else is flexible? Because time is such a complex concept that we cannot measure it or even theoretically define it, I think. If not, what is the problem with that and why is the speed of light given that much importance?

Comment: https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_clock

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity

Comment: But here you presume that speed of light is invariant. Also is it correct to represent time with light bouncing?

Comment: Physicists have no problem at all measuring time. Where did you get the idea that they do?

Comment: In classical physics, when you assume that time is absolute, there may be no problem by relating time directly to duration of some repetitive events. In relativity, however, you cannot do it. You say that space and time are different, and that time is also flexible like space, but then claim that positional (or other change in your time measurements which is not directly time) is time itself.

Comment: You said "In relativity, however, you cannot do it". Sure you can. What is "flexible" is coordinate time, but proper time is invariant in relativity. Proper time is what clocks measure. That invariant time is what is measured more accurately than any other quantity that we can measure.

Comment: Exactly to the point. If I get it right, you mean in Relativity time is actually invariant, however, processes slow down in moving frames and to represent this we introduce artificial time which is the fourth dimension in space-time. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can mathematics of relativity be interpreted in such a way that time is invariant and everything else is flexible?

Not to my knowledge, no. The time you call “flexible” is coordinate time and is frame variant and cannot be made invariant. However, in relativity there is also proper time, which is invariant. This is the time measured by a clock.

> time is such a complex concept that we cannot measure it

This is phenomenally wrong. Not only can we measure time, we can measure it far more precisely than any other quantity. A large part of modern metrology is converting other measurements into measurements of time specifically so that we can use our ability to precisely measure time to precisely measure other quantities.

> If not, what is the problem with that and why speed of light is given that much of importance?

The speed of light is important because it gives the conversion between our units of time and space. Once it is recognized that time and space belong together in a single geometric structure (spacetime) then many previously separate things become connected.

Comment: Could you please explain how you measure time? And why the speed of light, what is special with light?

Comment: If you mean bouncing light or atomic clock or something else, there you actually measure position not time.

Comment: Comments are not intended for discussion or for new questions. If you have more questions then you should post those separately. If you want to have a discussion then you should try physicsforums

Comment: I am accepting your answer, but please include your comment about proper time in your answer, and it would be better if you explain with just a sentence how proper time is invariant.

Comment: No problem! Done

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to measure time by counting reliably periodic events, such as the spinning of the Earth about its axis or the swings of a pendulum. Generally speaking, more accurate measurements can be made by picking events with shorter and more uniform periods. The most accurate clocks currently, known as atomic clocks, effectively count electron transitions between energy levels. The second is defined as the time which elapses over 9,192,631,770 of a particular type of transition in caesium atoms.

It used to be thought that time was the same everywhere- that was the assumption underlying Newtonian mechanics.

We now know from a lot of experimental evidence that the speed of light (in a vacuum) is a natural constant. One direct consequence of that is that the elapsed time between events will vary between moving reference frames.

There is no problem with defining time theoretically as a dimension. Disagreements about the meaning of time arise in connection with questions we cannot address experimentally. For example, some people take the view that there is only the present; others take the view that the past continues to exist, and some take the view that the future already exists. If you are interested in those debates try the search string 'philosophy of time' in your favourite search engine.

Comment: I understand, and I ask that is it possible to say that processes slow down and time is same? And then search for other reasons that slow them down? If not, why?

Comment: Or let me ask more precisely: In all the experiments "proving" relativity is it posssible to differentiate between slowing down and time?

Comment: No, because there is no difference between the two. If you are in a reference frame moving with respect to the Earth, ALL processes on Earth will appear to happen more slowly according to clocks moving with your reference frame. By definition time is the cumulative duration of clock-like processes, so if they slow time slows.

Comment: If not, then there is no difference between time and speed. Isn't it?

Comment: I mean you say that relative speed is different because there is time dilation, and then relate this time dilation measurement again to motion of something else. Isn't it like a paradox?

Comment: I suggest you should think as clearly as you can about why there appears to you to be a paradox, then ask another question about it. Whatever issue you have in mind is too elusive to resolve through these comments.

Answer (score -1):

> Can the mathematics of relativity be interpreted in such a way that time is invariant and everything else is flexible?

**No** : in-variance of $c$ is proved by [Kennedy & Thorndike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennedy%E2%80%93Thorndike_experiment) and variance of $t$ is proved by [Ives & Stilwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ives%E2%80%93Stilwell_experiment)

Comment: It is ok, I am just asking that, is another interpretation of these experiments and their corresponding math possible such that time is invariant?

Comment: Seems you don't get it. Every physical theory must be testable and compatible with existing experimental results. Experiments has showed that speed of light is the same in every reference frame. So once again, no - you can't create any theory/interpretation that $c$ is "flexible", unless you want your theory to be completely doomed from the start by existing experiments. BTW, not math rules the theories, but experiments who validates it !

Comment: If I ask what is speed of light, you will probably say it is the distance that light travels in one second, right?

Comment: But then what is second?

Comment: You say that there are lots of experiments. In those experiments how the time is measured?

Comment: Well, second may be defined as "_The second is the duration of `9'192'631'770` periods of the radiation corresponding to the transition between the two hyperfine levels of the ground state of the caesium 133 atom._" That's the definition by 1967 year. If you are interested about future new definitions of second or new better resolution of second measurements read about [optical clocks](https://www.nist.gov/si-redefinition/second/second-future) which has outperformed atomic clocks.

Comment: Speed of light $c$ does not necessarily is related with time at all. One can calculate it from Maxwell equations which is based only on vacuum capacitance and inductance : $$c={\frac {1}{\sqrt {\varepsilon _{0}\mu _{0}}}}\ .$$

Comment: Besides you forget that there are also a bunch of experiments which tests special relativity, and including, but not limited to test which confirms that time depends on a reference frame (time dilation). This experiment was done by [Ives–Stilwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ives%E2%80%93Stilwell_experiment) at 1938 year. So sorry, but time is not invariant, just forget that. You can't deny experimental results.

Comment: I think you admit that implicitly. In all your definitions time is given as duration of some process not time itself. So some processes may slow down but that does not necessarily mean that time dilate. There can be other factors that slow them down, isn't it?

Comment: "_some processes may slow down but that does not necessarily mean that time dilate_" - agree. However, if time dilates in some system,- then ALL processes in that reference frame slows down - including, but not limited to, person aging in that system. So in essence you intermix cause and effect. And Btw, there is no time concept which would be decoupled from any processes. It just happened so that photons are good at sampling any processes and thus- time also.

Comment: All sorts of alternative theories have been proposed, including ones that include this feature you're trying to promote.  **They were proven wrong**.  In fact, the theory of relativity came along because in the late 19th and early 20th century, people realized that *physics was broken*; it was Einstein who was the first to put his finger on the fact that it was broken because we were insisting that time be invariant.  Once you assume that $c$ is invariant and that time isn't, then physics becomes a lot less broken.  Google "the history of relativity" and read carefully.

Comment: This is a very good comment. You could put this as a separate answer. I would accept this answer if you also clarify this point: What was the main reason (issue) that lead scientists to think that time is not invariant? If relativity is not just a mathematical abstraction, there should be some conceptual and fundamental reasons behind this. Since time and speed are coupled together, saying that speed is constant and time is variant does not seem to be a satisfactory answer to me.